# Celery + gevent using only one CPU core

Tags: python, celery, gevent

I've issues with performance load running Celery with gevent, everything is running on the same core on my VPS.

Here's a screenshot of 4 Celery instance with 20 gevent concurrency each[image: .]

How to fix this ? What am I doing wrong ?

Here's my first task :

```
def update_sender():
    items = models.Item.objects.filter(active=True).all()
    count = items.count()
    items = [i.id for i in items]
    step = count / settings.WORKERS
    for job in list(chunks(items, step)):
        update_item.apply_async(args=[job])
```

Calling the following sub task:

```
def update_item(items):
    for item in items:
        try:
            i = models.Item.objects.get(id=item)
            url = "someurl"
            rep = requests.get(url)
            jrep = rep.json()
            tracker = ItemTracker(i, jrep)
            if tracker.skip():
                continue
            if tracker.method1():
                if not tracker.method2():
                    tracker.method3()
                tracker.save()
```

It's all about doing a lot of HTTP requests and updating database concurrently.

Comment: It's _very_ difficult to understand what's happening without any code to look at. Could you provide some?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you tend to stay *away* from multi-threaded applications on Python unless they're I/O intense, and you welcome multi-process applications instead unless they're I/O intense.  The likely scenario is that you've only got one process doing all of the heavy work and you're not doing anything with a multiprocessing framework.

Comment: In general you should not an usually cannot spin off threads from withing celery.  You should be creating new tasks and distributing them rather than trying to do that manually using gevent

Comment: But I'm not manually using gevent, just spawning gevent celery worker with the -P argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Celery with gevent still only uses a single process, its just starting multiple greenlets inside of the process, but it is still only executing one greenlet at a time.  To allow using more than 1 core, you need to start multiple celery processes using something like [celery-multi](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celery-users/RNZLiNyykQQ)

Comment: In the above examble, I started 4 celery instances. celery-multi doesn't work on supervisor :/

Comment: You can start multiple workers in supervisor rather than using multi, each specifying -P gevent.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did.