# Celery: why does its distributed tasks run slower than multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

My Computer has 16 cpu cores and tried to compare time to finish the task between `celery` and `multiprocessing`

Here is experiments
(`update_daily_price` is the method to crawl some stock daily price data of given symbol from the web)

1) Single thread process

**code**

```
for s in symbol_list:
    update_daily_price(symbol)
```

It took total "12mins 54secs"

2) `muliprocessing` libarary

**code**

```
pool = Pool(8)
pool.map(update_daily_price, symbol_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

It took total "2mins 10secs"

3) `celery`'s apply_async()

I started worker process by `celery --workdir=trading/ --concurrency=8 -P eventlet worker`

And run task like these:

**code**

```
@shared_task
def update_dailyprice_task1(symbol):
    update_daily_price(symbol)

from celery import group
jobs = group(update_dailyprice_task1.s(symbol) for symbol in symbol_list)
jobs.apply_async()
```

It took total "10mins 24secs"

As you can see here, there is almost not that big difference between `1)` and `3)`. Am I missing something on performing distributing celery tasks?

Comment: I think the problem is you are using blocking IO. Take a look: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet. If you want to use `eventlet`, you should make sure you are using non-blocking IO. A simple way to check is using default `multiprocessing` and check the performance.

Comment: @Sraw, I saw that and also refer the code in https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/eventlet... As you can see the code at bottom of in this site, it also used `apply_async()`... What's the "blocking IO" part you said in my code?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems `celery` implicitly "greenify" all modules. So maybe there is some calculation bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @Sraw If there is a calculation bottleneck in my code, it should turn out to be slow even in `multiprocessing` test, too

Comment: No, `multiprocessing` could use multiple cores(cpus), but `eventlet` only use one cpu to execute all tasks.

Comment: @Sraw The why does celery have distributing-task features if it runs  tasks only using one cpu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31142278/5588279 You can launch multiple celery instances on one host or more hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this by using [billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard)

Reference : https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4525

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your celery command:

```
celery --workdir=trading/ --concurrency=8 -P eventlet worker
```

According to [this page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html),you're asking celery to create one worker with 8 green threads. Which is different from creating 8 processes. This will effectively create one process that uses 8 threads. Since your function is probably computation heavy, you end up having comparable results to the one process execution.

In order to use multiple processes, you need to use the prefork workers. Using the following command will get you comparable results to the `multiprocessing` library:

```
celery --workdir=trading/ --concurrency=8 worker
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue as well : `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`. I solved this by using billiard

Comment: Btw, your advices are really helpful cuz I don't even know what the `-P eventlet` means. Is it common case to use `-P eventlet` this option? that might depend on the computer I use?